# Unable to start SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-agent

We are unable to start SQL server Agent and it fails with below error:

> SQLServerAgent could not be started (reason: SQLServerAgent must be
> able to connect to SQLServer as SysAdmin, but '(Unknown)' is not a
> member of the SysAdmin role).

1. Checked that Service account to run agent is added in admin group on the server.
2. Checked that it is added as sysadmin with the security of sql server login:

The account used to run is a domain account which has sufficient privileges since sql server is using that account to run the same in production:

SQl server here is SQL server 2005 Enterprise edition

Adding @ Also when i tried to check status agent xp with `EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'Agent XPs'` it says run value 0.

So i tried running :

```
EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'Agent XPs',1
GO
RECONFIGURE with override
```

But no success and fails with below error:

> Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 1 to 1. Run the
> RECONFIGURE statement to install. Msg 5845, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Address Windowing Extensions (AWE) requires the 'lock pages in memory'
> privilege which is not currently present in the access token of the
> process.

But run value is still 0

[image]

Please suggest what could be done here?

Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24587/discussion-between-kasqldba-and-shanky).

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL Server configuration manager to change the SQL Server Agent user account.

Change it to run as local system, apply and restart and then back to the correct user, dont add any privileges to the user in the operating system (esp. not add it to the server local administrator group). The Configuration manager will set all the correct permissions for the account.

Comment: Thanks @sporri, but even that did not worked. we have got this resolved and its weird, but it got resolved by moving the cluster to a different node and disabling & enabling AWE back within server properties, we still wonder what happened but this fixed